# keyboard navigation with tab key

Tags: jquery, navigation, keyboard, keycode, nodelist

I'd like to be able to tab through menu and dropdowns, and once 'lastDropdown' is reached, for previous dropdown to 'display:none' - why isn't 'if conditional' working?

Here's my jquery and javascript ..

```
    $('li > a').keydown(function(e){

var subMenuChildren = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var subMenu = $(this).next('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < subMenuChildren.length; i++){
  var lastDropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('lastDropdown');

  if (e.which == 9 && subMenuChildren !== lastDropdown) {
    subMenu.addClass('open');
  }
  else{
    subMenu.removeClass('open');
  }
}
});
```

Here's my html ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Keyboard Navigation - LRR</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navigation-container">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Meet The Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Team Activities</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lastDropdown">
          <a href="#">Mission and Vision</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Big Island Go-Tos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Moving To Kona 101</a>
          </li>
          <li class="lastDropdown">
          <a href="#">Island News</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Search MLS</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="lastDropdown">
          <a href="#">Kona Searches</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu-navigation.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start off by saying that I won't answer for your specific question as it is not educating the community and not reproduced by other users.

What you should do is make your element's be able to navigate using the ["tabindex=0"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attributes.

This will enable using the 'tab' key to navigate and you can catch when the element has ":focus" activated to manage functionality.

Example:

```
<div tabindex="0">reachable</div>
<a href="#" tabindex="-1">Tab key cannot reach here!</a>
```